# Is there a way to represent summary rows with OData?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

I'm trying to tack on additional information to the list of items returned from an `ODataController`'s method. The use case is summary rows. So we basically want to return the rows of the report and then also additional info with totals, sub-totals, etc.

So, basically starting with this method:

```
public PageResult<MyReportLine> Get(ODataQueryOptions odataQueryOptions)
```

I tried wrapping `MyReportLine` in `MyReport`

```
public class MyReport {
    IEnumerable<MyReportLine> _myReportLines;
    MySummaryRow _mySummaryRow;
}
```

and then returning this `MyReport` object.

```
public PageResult<MyReport> Get(ODataQueryOptions odataQueryOptions)
```

This approach seemed to mess up all the querying mechanisms because the query supplied in the URI was targeting `MyReportLine`, but `MyReport` is the actual class that's exposed. I don't think that the wrapper/summary should be a first-class entity...

Is there a recommended approach to this task?

Answer (score 0):

You should use ODataQueryOptions i.e

```
public PageResult<MyReport> Get(ODataQueryOptions<MyReportLine> odataQueryOptions)
```

Comment: Thanks! Just got around to trying it and it gives me a 406. Do I need to play with the routes, too? If so - then how?

Comment: Looks like you are using ODataController. You should have an OData route if you are using ODataController. Use ApiController if you are just trying to have OData query semantics and not the whole OData semantics.