# How to return a different object from the one you run a query on in OData?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

I'm trying to return an object from the controller's `Get` method that is of a different class from the class the query is run on.

Based on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16470823/is-there-a-way-to-represent-summary-rows-with-odata), this is what I'm doing:

```
public PageResult<OutputPoco> Get(ODataQueryOptions<InputPoco> odataQueryOptions)
```

When trying to run this I get `406 Not Acceptable`. What am I missing? Is there a working example out there of this approach?

Update:
I am using `ODataController`.
`OutputPoco` contains a reference to `InputPoco`. I need sorting and filtering to work (on `InputPoco`).

Answer (score 2):

Are you using ODataController? You have to use ODataController only when you are building OData service. In that case you have to build an EDM model and then expose the OData service using an odata route.

If you just want to build a vanilla web API that just supports OData query semantics (and not rest of OData like url conventions and formatting), you should use ApiController instead.

Comment: I am using ODataController. If I map the route using modelBuilder.EntitySet<InputPoco> I get a 406. If I map the route using modelBuilder.Entity<OutputPoco> the code complains about navigational properties (since OutputPoco contains a reference to InputPoco). Any combination I try there's something that's breaking. Is there a working example out there with this approach, using sorting, filtering, etc.?

Comment: We have a bunch of samples [here](https://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/ReadMe.txt). These two might interest you most -[ODataServiceSample](https://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/ODataServiceSample/ReadMe.txt), [ODataQueryableSample](https://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/ODataQueryableSample/ReadMe.txt).

Comment: Took a look at the samples. I don't think they have what I'm looking for. Basically, I need two classes: A and B. B has a collection of A. Need to query and sort on A and then return B with a list of A fully expanded.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create an class to represent odata return like:
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

```
/// <summary>
/// For odata list compatibility.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">Type of model.</typeparam>
public class ODataListResult<T>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ODataListResult{T}"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="totalcount">totalcount.</param>
    /// <param name="value">value.</param>
    public ODataListResult(long totalcount, List<T> value)
    {
        this.Totalcount = totalcount;
        this.Value = value;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or Sets Totalcount.
    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty("@odata.count")]
    public long Totalcount { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or Sets Value.
    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public List<T> Value { get; set; }
}
```

and use it like that:

```
/// <summary>
        /// Obter TEntitys por filtro.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="query">Query.</param>
        /// <returns>Lista de TEntity gerados pelo sistema.</returns>
        [HttpGet]
        ////[EnableQuery]
        public IActionResult Get(ODataQueryOptions<Comment> query)
        {
            long count;
            var list = ObjService.GetAllNoTracking(query, out count);
            var page = new ODataListResult<CommentDto>(count, list);
            return Ok(page);
        }
```